# SoundCloud API for app for search

Tags: javascript, html, api, soundcloud

I know the basic API of soundcloud. How can I search a track in SoundCloud without asking the user (who is logged into my website) to login/create an account in soundcloud?

I have to initialize the soundcloud with my client id before making any API call.

```
SC.initialize({
   client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});
```

I don't want to pass client id to search. How can we do.

Comment: you have to post what you have tried :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can have some server side code (you didn't mention anything about it) you could make the request with your YOUR_CLIENT_ID.
Tough your question need to be more specific, and the SoundCloud API seems easy to understand.
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to pass client id to search.

You're asking the impossible.  SoundCloud **requires** a Client ID for any API integrations.  It's just their rules.

You don't need a user to sign in with their account to use the API for search.  Just create an API application, initialize the client with your Client ID, and call `get`.  Example:

```
SC.get('/tracks', {
  q: 'Chvrches'
}).then(function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```